# How to make Symfony Form to use addSomething() / removeSomething() methods of the underlying object?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Suppose I have `User` object, which has `$emails` field. User object also has `addEmail()` and `removeEmail()` methods. 
In my form type (`UserType`) I use `CollectionType` for `$emails` field.
After submitting a form, I want methods `User::addEmail()` and `User::removeEmail()` to be called instead of `User::setEmails()`. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you just have to add the option 'by_reference' => false when building the form field.